# how to save in SQLite Manager?

Tags: sqlite

I have opened a sqlite3 database file in firefox sqlite manager, made some changes to it but I can't see a way to save it?

There are various export options such as CSV, SQL and XML

I am new to this and just updating someone else's work

Comment: Not sure about with that addon, but personally I'd recomment SQLite Data Browser:
http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ Apologies if this isn't helpful.

Comment: don't think it would run on a mac

Answer (score 1):

It's a database. The result of data affecting queries is saved as executed in the database, such as:

- `CREATE TABLE`
- `ALTER TABLE`
- `DROP TABLE`
- `INSERT`
- `UDPATE`
- `DELETE`

Comment: Ok but none of my changes have been made in xcode, i've tried closing and opening the project - perhaps i should just ask "how do i update a sqlite database in xcode?"

Comment: @jimsmith Yes, knowing the nature of the problem would allow us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the data grid editor, then once the `UPDATE` query has run, the changes are ALREADY committed in the database.

If you are using the SQL area and typed your own `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements: SQLite by default uses one-statement transactions; you can however manually start and end a transaction with `BEGIN;` and `END;` or `COMMIT;`.

So, if you ran an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement, it has been committed and you cannot rollback.

Comment: do you know xcode? I have opened the .sqlite3 from the project in the manager but no changes are being implemented - tried closing and reopening the project

Answer (score 0):

06/10/15 this page is no longer there . . .
http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/wiki/ExecuteSQL

Save [and delete] Query By Name

SELECT Queries and other SQL statements can be stored in a SQLite database and rerun at a later time from the Execute SQL tab of SQLite Manager.

To enable this functionality, go to the Tools menu in the Menu bar and check the Use Table for Extension Data item.

To save an SQL statement, click on the Save Query icon in the Execute SQL tab, which will prompt you to enter a query name.

To retrieve the SQL query, select it by name from the drop down menu below the Enter SQL text box.

The text of the statement will be written to the Enter SQL text box where it can be modified if necessary before being run.

To delete a saved query statement from the menu, run the following sql statement containing the query name in the Enter SQL text box.

```
DELETE FROM __sm_ext_mgmt WHERE type = "NamedQuery: query_name"
```

---

I don't understand this syntax.  Maybe I'm not entering it in the right place.  None of these worked.  I tried to run these like the query:

Syntax:

```
DELETE FROM __sm_ext_mgmt WHERE type = "NamedQuery: query_name"
```

My attempts:

```
DELETE FROM __sm_ext_mgmt WHERE type = "NamedQuery: Export Bookmarks to CSV"
DELETE FROM __sm_ext_mgmt WHERE type = "NamedQuery: Export Bookmarks to CSV with
```

Date-Time"

```
DELETE FROM __sm_ext_mgmt WHERE type = "Export Bookmarks to CSV"
DELETE FROM __sm_ext_mgmt WHERE type = "Export Bookmarks to CSV with Date-Time"
```

---

I highlighted this table:

```
__sm_ext_mgmt<br>
```

. . . I then clicked the Browse & Search tab

I right-clicked on the two in there that were my queries / Delete / and they're gone from the list now

A lot of other stuff was in there, previous entries that I did.

11/03/14 I think I can delete this type (06/10/15 just leave it):
. . . QueryHistory

But I need to keep these 5 types:

```
. . . StructTree:ExpandedCategories
. . . StructTree:ExpandedObjects
. . . StructTree:AttachedDb
. . . Enabled
. . . BrowseTree:ColState:table:_sm_ext_mgmt
```

Everything still seems to be working properly

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question or are you trying to ask a question here?

Comment: It is the answer, with some comments

Comment: I had to re-set up my query, and forgot how to save it.  I found this page, with no answer.  I then thought, "Hey, I figured this out before, it must be in my notes."  So yes, it was, and here they are!

Answer (score 0):

File -> Download active Database